# Seeking an alternative to the big browsers

Tags: software-recommendation, safari, google-chrome, firefox, web-browsing

Can anyone recommend any alternative web-browsers to the Big Three of Safari, Google Chrome and Firefox?

I just want to try something new, because I'm not completely happy with the performance of those three. Maybe there's something better out there that I'm not aware of yet. I need your advice.

Comment: Websites are programmed to work best for the most used browsers. If you use an uncommon browser you might have display and feature issues on certain websites.

Comment: Good luck finding anything (useful) that's faster than Chrome.  What is the problem you're experiencing?  Perhaps your web browser isn't the real problem.

Comment: Indeed, if you are looking for different features the below suggestions might suit you, but it is not going to outperform Chrome on the Mac.

Comment: Don't assume speed is the performance factor in this post, it could be security, plugins, development work, we just do not know. Yes Chrome is the fastest, but is also less secure than Opera and Firefox. So it may not be the best performer in the OP's mind. Over to you OP, What performance factors are you looking for specifically?

Comment: Do you want a different browser for the sake of being different or because you have real issues with the popular (and best supported, most widely used) browsers?

Comment: Well, not that I have many issues with the popular briwsers, but I just want to know if there is something else out there that could outperform them. To prove my point: just think about Windows OS. It is by far the most popular OS in the world, whereas we all know that it is by far not the best one. It could be true for web-browsers as well.

Answer (score 7):

### [Opera](http://www.opera.com/)

is the next biggest after the main lot

Opera also has a mobile version, the idea of Opera is to load all of the HTML and files before it displays anything, so it loads full web pages faster than most

The next important thing about Opera is that it has support from webmasters. If you look at Apple source code on their websites it mentions support for recgonsising opera as a browser, alongside the others

The problem with using other browsers is that some websites may not fully function. So it is safer an easier to go with one of these.

Comment: Well, since this site is devoted to mention IE as one of the most used browsers (unless you're a hardcore oldie that keeps using pre-2006 technologies at all costs).
As for Opera, I think, I should give it a try.

Comment: Opera is good, its got a clean UI and works well. It is often seen in code now and suooprted by webmasters,I have added this to my answer

Comment: -1 - IE is not one of the main 4 on a Mac.  It's nothing.

Comment: @james.garriss can you clarify firstly where  it says Mac? I refered to the overall web browser market, not just on Mac.

Comment: LOL.  Um, what website is this?  "Ask Different:  Answers for your Apple questions."  If the OP is looking for help on his Win7 box, he's on the wrong site.

Comment: correct, but they will need to post that information, you wouldn't believe how many people come here asking very odd non apple related questions. So like I said I refered to the overal useage, this means other people asking this question on the web will want recieve information, not just those on an Apple computer. So I will argue that this is information that can be usefull to other people not just you or the OP. after all that is what these sites are for, I hope that settles your dislike of my mention of IE.

Comment: Sorry, poor questions by other posters don't really change anything.

Comment: If you have a chance to try Opera Next too, I recommend. It's still alpha but comes with many new nice features.

Comment: "Across all platforms" in a misnomer. Across all versions of Windows maybe. But IE doesn't run (natively) in Linux nor OS X, and certainly not on any other non-Windows platform.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say [Omniweb](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniweb/) by the [Omnigroup](http://www.omnigroup.com/).

Comment: Omniweb is using the Safari Webkit Engine

Comment: But an engine is different from a browser. Chrome uses Webkit also, but Chrome and Safari aren't the same thing.

Comment: [*OmniWeb*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OmniWeb) was retired, yet mysteriously I see a new [version 6 preview build](https://omnistaging.omnigroup.com/omniweb/) in early 2018. [Release Notes](https://update.omnigroup.com/releasenotes/omniweb/OmniWeb-r307108-Test/) says: Current test builds of OmniWeb 6.0 require El Capitan (macOS 10.11) or later. (The current development target is High Sierra, i.e. macOS 10.13.)

Answer (score 2):

### [OmniWeb](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniweb/)

Probably the best alternative to the well known browsers.
 Enjoy visual tabs and the ability to block ads.

### [Opera](http://www.opera.com/download/?platform=mac)

Enjoy fast browsing on slow connections, with Opera Turbo.
 Build-in support for Bittorrent.

### [Cruz](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cruz/id402357089?mt=12)

View multiple web pages simultaneously in sidebar split views.
  Powerful userscript features.

### [iCab](http://www.icab.de/)

Highly configurable browser.

### [Demeter](http://www.hurrikenux.com/Demeter/)

Cocoa- based browser that has the ability to connect to all of your favorite social networks. Based on **Shiira**.

### [Sunrise](http://www.sunrisebrowser.com/)

Open source browser with multiple language support.
 Website snapshot is build-in.

### [Stainless](http://www.stainlessapp.com/)

A multi-process browser for OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Camino](https://caminobrowser.org/), a Mac OS X-native browser built on Mozilla's Gecko rendering engine.

Comment: Camino has been practically abandoned, since with Firefox 4 Mozilla decided to stop Gecko embedding. That means that Camino will either be stuck with Firefox 3.6 Gecko or they'll have to switch to Webkit (quite lengthy process).

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Raven](http://raven.io/index.html), it comes with great features. I use as my everyday browser at Home!

I just remembered another one, it its [Sleipnir](http://www.fenrir-inc.com/us/mac/sleipnir/), a very nice browser with suport to gestures and a sleek interface.

Answer (score 1):

**Brave** and **Vivaldi** are two good alternative browsers being actively developed for macOS as of 2018-03. Brave is also available for iOS.

## Brave

[image]

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(web_browser)):

> [*Brave*](https://vivaldi.com/) is a free and open-source web browser based on the Chromium web browser and its Blink engine, announced by the co-founder of the Mozilla project and creator of JavaScript, Brendan Eich. It claims to block website trackers and remove intrusive Internet advertisements. The browser also claims to improve online privacy by sharing less data with advertising customers.

## Vivaldi

[image]

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivaldi_(web_browser)):

> [*Vivaldi*](https://vivaldi.com/) is a freeware, cross-platform web browser developed by Vivaldi Technologies, a company founded by Opera Software co-founder and former CEO Jon Stephenson von Tetzchner and Tatsuki Tomita. The browser was officially launched on April 12, 2016. The browser is aimed at staunch technologists, heavy Internet users, and previous Opera web browser users disgruntled by Opera's transition from the Presto layout engine to the Blink layout engine, which removed many popular features. Vivaldi aims to revive the old, popular features of Opera 12.

## Others

I regularly use both Brave & Vivaldi. Others **I have *not* tried** that seem to be actively developed for macOS:

- [Torch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torch_(browser))
- [SRWare Iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRWare_Iron)
- [Sleipnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleipnir_(web_browser))
- [SeaMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaMonkey)
- [Falkon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falkon) (formerly QupZilla)
- [OmniWeb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OmniWeb) (formerly retired, new [preview release in 2018](https://omnistaging.omnigroup.com/omniweb/))
- [NetSurf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetSurf)
- [Maxthon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxthon)
- [Dooble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dooble)
- [Cliqz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliqz)

## Comparison of web browsers

Wikipedia maintains a [list comparing various web browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers). You may want to peruse that list for alternatives.

Comment: +1 for Brave - I'm liking what I see with it on iOS and initial impressions on macOS. Building a modern browser is really a huge engineering challenge and it's refreshing to see some new attempts.

Answer (score 0):

### [RockMelt](http://www.rockmelt.com/)

Billed as the best of Chrome with the best of Social Networking on top of it. Instant access to Facebook, YouTube, Twitter, CNN and more. Completely free, Mac only on the desktop, and they have an [iPhone app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rockmelt/id416256246?mt=8) (App Store Link) as well.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on what you want to do with your browser. If it is mainly Web 2.0, you're probably best off with one of the popular browsers.

If you're unsatisfied with the performance of the browsers, the fastest browsers I know are text-browsers like [links](http://links.twibright.com/) or [lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/). Links also offers a graphics mode, which is sufficient for displaying many websites.

I just mentioned those browsers, as you were searching for alternatives you may not be aware off. Links or lynx won't replace your default browser, but are an alternative in certain cases.